# If there is any other opportunity to make for cycle in swift >= 2.2?

Tags: swift, for-loop

Just saw some deprecations (classic for loop for example) in swift 2.2 and wanted to ask if it is any other way to write for-in cycle with step more that 1 than this variation:

```
for i in 100.stride(through: 500, by: 50){
  print(i)
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The basic for-loop has many variants, but it's not clear what you're really asking here.  What you have may be the easiest way of printing out 1, 51, etc. with swift 2.2 short of unwrapping the for loop `var i = 1; while i < 500 { print(i); i = i + 50 }`

Comment: I know that is possible with while, but any other options with for?

Comment: Using the stride function is the correct way to do it.